# Nokia X IAP getProductDetails() and getPurchases() error for published product

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, nokia, nokiax

I'm trying to add Nokia IAP in my app and following the exact code as stated in [Nokia In-App Payment Guide](http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/nokia-x/nokia-in-app-payment/nokia-in-app-payment-porting-guide.html).

I've tested with test IDs, I can get product details and also I can purchase the item. But with an actual product, with a **Published (revision 7)** publication status, although I can purchase it using the `getBuyIntent()` method, I cannot get product details. I'm using the method `getProductDetails()` inside an **AsyncTask** `doInBackground()` method. And I'm getting the response from the returned bundle via:

```
ArrayList<String> responseList = result.getStringArrayList("DETAILS_LIST");
```

The `responseList` size is 1, and it contains the 7-digit product ID looks like:

```
{"isvalid":false,"productId":"*******"}
```

But it should contain the product details with price, right?

Also when I try to restore using `getPurchases()` method, it's returning with an error code 6. And if I try:

```
ArrayList<String> items = mBundle.getStringArrayList("INAPP_PURCHASE_ITEM_LIST");
```

The `items` object is always `null`.

Can anyone please help what's wrong and how to fix these? I'm using the Nokia X emulator and my product id is the numeric one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `getProductDetails()` method:

- Based on [Dr. Jukka](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3305005/dr-jukka)'s answer, if an alias is created for a product, that **must** be used inside the code instead of the default numeric one.

For `getPurchases()` method:

- All the codes for getting purchases should be inside an **AsyncTask**. The [Nokia In-App Payment Guide](http://developer.nokia.com/resources/library/nokia-x/nokia-in-app-payment/nokia-in-app-payment-developer-guide/adding-nokia-in-app-payment-to-your-apps.html) only refers that the `getProductDetails()` method should not be executed in the main thread and nothing is specified for `getPurchases()` method. I wasn't using the **AsyncTask** while restoring which always returned error code 6. Now it works using the **AsyncTask**.

**N.B.** The `getBuyIntent()` method however doesn't need an **AsyncTask**, it works fine without it.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using setProductMappings-method? If not, are you giving productBundle for getPurchases? One of those is needed to be able to use getPurchases. I am not sure why you have problem with getProductDetails, but let's solve getPurchases problem first.

Comment: No I'm not using `setProductMappings()`. Yes I'm giving productBundle as it's a needed parameter for the method `getPurchases()`. I'm creating the product bundle just as specified in the IAP guide. The code is: `mBundle = mBillingService.getPurchases(NOKIA_IAP_API_VERSION, mContext.getPackageName(), ITEM_TYPE_INAPP, generateProductBundle(), null);`
The method `generateProductBundle()` returns a bundle with the product list.

Answer (score 1):

Another reason I got from our internal experts could be that if you are using the **Product ID Alias** then you **must** use it.

Thus to check the item from the publicer portal, and see whether you have set the **Product ID Alias** and indeed if you have set it, then see that you are using it.

Comment: Thanks, it's now working for me when I'm getting product details using the alias. But still the restoration is not working. The returned bundle is not null anymore while restoring, it's size is 1, but the error code is still 6.

Comment: ok, You managed to puzzle our internal experts now. One Question though, did you change the IMEI of the emulator to some value that would be used with real device (RDA, or other) ?

Comment: In general Real-ID's purchases should not work in, so you shouldn't be able to buy anything in there with real IDs, however if the devie with the set IMEI has purchased the item, it might show other results.

Comment: One suggestion other from experts, was to try out the restorable test ID 1023623 for verifying the logic funcitonality.

Comment: Nope I haven't changed IMEI or anything inside the emulator at all. I've also tried the test ID **1023623**, it doesn't restore as well. Same result, bundle with size 1 and error code 6. But I've fixed it now, posting the answer below.